# scp/secure copy most recent file from remote android device / SSH Server

Tags: android, bash, ssh

I have set up an Android phone with the "SSH Server" app and would like to write a script to download the latest file in a particular directory using scp. The script is to be run from a Linux laptop

The problem is that the android doesn't contain commands like "head" or "tail" and I don't know how to select the latest file.

The best I can do is copy all the files from a directory with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dst=username@192.168.1.107:storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
scp -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst/* /home/username/projects/3patetas
done 0
```

Can anyone help?

-------EDIT-------------

I thought the following might work but it causes the ssh server on the android to stop:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_dir=/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
dst=username@192.168.1.107
scp -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst:'ssh $dst cd $remote_dir ; latest="" ; for i in *.jpg ; do latest=$i ; done ; echo $latest' /home/username/projects/3patetas
exit 0
```

Comment: `ls -1t | grep -m 1 .`?

Comment: Thanks. The "grep -m 1 ." part works, as does the pipe, but "ls" doesn't recognise "-1t"

Comment: "ls -t | grep -m 1 ." would be sufficient but ls doesn't have the -t option

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_dir=/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
dst=username@192.168.1.107
name="$(ssh $dst "cd $remote_dir"' ; latest="" ; for i in *.jpg ; do latest=$i ; done ; echo $latest')"
scp -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst:$remote_dir/$name /home/username/projects/3patetas
exit 0
```

Or this:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_dir=/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
dst=username@192.168.1.107
name=($(ssh $dst "cd $remote_dir"' ; for i in *.jpg ; do date +%s -r $i ; echo $i ; done'))
name=$(printf "%s %s\n" ${name[@]} | sort -n | tail -1)
scp -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst:$remote_dir/${name#* } /home/username/projects/3patetas
exit 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It's better. I needed to add the port number and the host key type to the "name " variable, ie. 

#!/bin/bash
remote_dir=/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera
dst=iain@192.168.1.17
name="$(ssh -p 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst "cd $remote_dir"' ; latest="" ; for i in *.jpg ; do latest=$i ; done ; echo $latest')"
scp -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst:$remote_dir/$name /home/iain/projects/3patetas
exit 0

However, it gives an odd error message:

com.icecoldapps.sshserver.a.h@42301f30 not a regular file

Comment: @escuta and BTW check the alternative verison I just posted. Android does have `date` and `echo`, and the remaining code running locally ensures that the file is really the last by modification date.

Comment: Thanks, tried the 2nd version. It still comes up against the same problem - error message: com.icecoldapps.sshserver.a.h@423a8500 not a regular file

Comment: @escuta can you please execute the SSH line alone and see if the error persists? I mean, erase the SCP line and all that comes next, but leave `remote_dir` and `dst` setting.

Comment: I executed the 1st 3 lines one by one in a terminal, ie. the remote_dir and dst setting and then the ssh line. It gives this error: "exec request failed on channel 0" and the value of name is null

Comment: @escuta that\`s bad. Android SSH server is refusing to execute commands. That\`s pretty normal, however, because password-less SSH login + remote commands = security hole. The only way out I now see is to allow remote commands and protect SSH sessions with an encryption key, so that no one except you (or someone bearing your full credentials from the main laptop, of course) could access the device.

Comment: I created a passwordless RSA key pair on the Linux machine and loaded the public key into the ssh server app on the android. I can now ssh to the android with out logging in (and do simple scp commands from linux), but the  "exec request failed on channel 0" error message continues. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I should mention that I can run all the commands in the script manually via ssh, just not with the script

Comment: @escuta does `ssh -P 60839 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $dst /bin/sh <<<"echo ALIVE"` executed from the script output "ALIVE"?

Comment: Thought about trying rsync but I also encounter the exec request error. I tried this: rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 57846 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss" username@192.168.1.12:/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera /home/username/projects/3patetas

Comment: Thanks for your help @hidefromkgb. I'm using the "scp usr@remote:dir/* /home/user/localdir/*" blunderbuss approach for now in this little project. Very slow and inefficient. Hopefully someone will appear to suggest a better way. I've tried a few other ssh server apps but the result is the same.